# What are necessary and sufficient conditions for property injection work in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have the following class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Database {

   ...

   @Value("${database.driver-class-name}")
   public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
      ...
   }
```

Have the following dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
```

Have the following line in `application.properties`:

```
database.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Have the following annotations on test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(DatabaseTest.Context.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DatabaseTest {

   @Configuration
   public static class Context {

      @Bean
      public Database database() {
         Database ans = new Database();
         return ans;
      }

   }

   @Autowired
   public Database database;
```

and it still neither inject properties from property file nor swears with some error message.

What else it wants?

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for properties to inject from propery file?

**UDPATE**

Sample repository: https://github.com/dims12/MinimalRequrementsToInjectPropertiesFromFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, found an answer myself.

In the case of Spring Boot, a context configuration class is usually annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which causes many things, including automatic finding an wiring of property files. This is invoked by `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, which is contained inside former annotation.

In my case, I have annotated context configuration class with plain-Spring `@Configuration` annotation only, because I was in `JUnit` test and thought it is not an application. In this case I was to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` explicitly.

Probably I was also allowed to annotate context configuration class with `@SpringBootApplication`, but I didn't test it.

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` was not needed at all. Also no need for `@ConfigurationProperties`, and `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `@configurationProperties` on your class should have `@Bean` or `@Component` annotation  for the spring to inject property values . More information about properties can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component // or @Bean
public class Database {
```

Comment: If I annotate bean with `@Component` should I remove it from `Context` then?

Comment: If you do that, you can remove inner class `Context` completely.

Comment: Does not work anyway. If I remove class completely, it swears it can't run without config. If I retain empty class and annotate it `@ComponentScan`, it works, but doesn't inject properties.

Comment: @Dims Sorry for the late reply.. I think you don't need to have `@Bean` in your case, because it is a inner class. 1. If you need a database instance you can autowire it directly, by specifying `@Component` or `@Bean` on  your class, is there any reason why do you take a inner class?

Comment: Inner class is a config class. It can be standalone, nothing change in the case.

Comment: Here is an example without inner class: https://github.com/dims12/MinimalRequrementsToInjectPropertiesFromFile/tree/trying-outer

Comment: @Dims I'll take a look into your project